# Automate launching and performing GUI operations in Java Web Start application

Tags: automation, sikuli, gui-testing

I want to automate GUI testing that involves following steps.

1. Open a URL in my web browser (Internet Explorer).  The page at this URL will contain a link.
2. Click the link on the page.  This will download a JNLP and launch the Java Web Start application automatically.
3. The application will have some text fields that need to be filled in and some buttons that need to be pressed.

How can I automate this?

**Platform**: Windows

**Edit**: I'm looking at Sikuli as a possible method of automating this, but I don't know if it will be able to switch between applications from the web browser (in step 1) to the Java application (in step 3). Are there any other tools available (preferably open source) that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli will be able to switch between the two applications, for sure. It's quite good at that sort of thing, since it's agnostic about the underlying GUI technology.

In my opinion, Sikuli sounds like the fastest and easiest way to get your test scenario automated, because otherwise you may need to deal with two frameworks (one for automating the web browser and another for your Java application).